# What does gstreamer's h264parse really do?

Tags: h.264, gstreamer-1.0

I'm confused with what `h264parse` really does.

I tested with this commands:

with `h264parse`:

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc num-buffers=10 ! x264enc ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

without `h264parse`:

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc num-buffers=10 ! x264enc ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

it makes no difference and both work fine.

Then I tried to save h264 into file and then open it.

save it into file:

```sh
gst-launch-1.0  videotestsrc num-buffers=10 ! x264enc ! filesink location=videotestsrc.h264
```

Open it with h264parse, it works ok and I can see the video:

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=videotestsrc.h264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

But if I open it without `h264parse`:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=videotestsrc.h264 ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

it does not work and the error message is like this:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/avdec_h264:avdec_h264-0: GStreamer error: negotiation problem.
Additional debug info:
gstvideodecoder.c(2448): gst_video_decoder_chain (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/avdec_h264:avdec_h264-0:
decoder not initialized
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I don't know how to understand it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/libav/avdec_h264.html?gi-language=c#sink) of ***avdec_h264***, his sink expects parsed format of ***h264*** stream. And what ***[h264parse](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videoparsersbad/h264parse.html?gi-language=c#src)*** does, it just parses bytes of ***h264*** in a way that ***avdec_h264*** could understand.

```
# avdec_h264 sink
video/x-h264:
      alignment: au
      stream-format: { (string)avc, (string)byte-stream }
      video/x-h264:
      alignment: nal
      stream-format: byte-stream

# h264parse src
video/x-h264:
      parsed: true
      stream-format: { (string)avc, (string)avc3, (string)byte-stream }
      alignment: { (string)au, (string)nal }
```

So, ***h264parse*** doesn't decode ***h264*** bytes into the raw video stream, it just assembles bytes in some form.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question/answer after asking myself the same thing. After a bit more research, I thought I should share my findings.

I found that the 'alignment' property in `avdec_h264` corresponds to the frames used in `gst_pad_push`. In other-words, if alignment is 'nal', then avdec_h264 expects the data in a single `gst_pad_push` call to be a single 'nal'.

Because the `filesrc` element has no idea what it is working with, it doesn't provide `avdec_h264` data in the frame alignment it expects.

I created a plugin which can parse a stream of data and split on any arbitrary sequence of bytes. This can be used to provide `avdec_h264` the correct frames.

The source-code for the plugin can be found here:
https://github.com/redmcg/gst-buffer-splitter